# how to use ng-repeat in append to get the key value?

Tags: jquery, angularjs

if i use ng-repeat in append html div, the content is not appending. how to get the label name key value on appended each fields. i want to change each label name from field label options from below code. click on appended div, it will shows filed label options, from there i have to change each label name seperately.. pls help me

```js
var app = angular.module('myapp', ['ngSanitize']);

app.controller('AddCtrl', function ($scope, $compile) {

    $scope.field = {single: 'untitled'};
    $scope.addNew_SingleField = function (index) {
              var singlehtml = '<fieldset ng-repeat="(fieldkey, field) in singleField" ng-click="selectSingle($field)"><label ng-bind-html="field.single"></label><input type="text" placeholder="Enter name" name="{{field.single}}"><button ng-click="removeSingle($index)">-</button></fieldset>';
        var single = $compile(singlehtml)($scope);
        angular.element(document.getElementById('drop')).append(single);
    };
    $scope.removeSingle = function (index) {
            var myEl = angular.element(document.querySelector('#single_field'));
        myEl.remove();
    };
    $scope.selectSingle = function (field) {
      selectedField = field
      $scope.showSingle_Fieldsettings = true;
    };
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myapp">

<head>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-beta.2/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.0-rc.0/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="AddCtrl">
 <button ng-click="addNew_SingleField($index)">Single Line Text</button>
 <div id="drop"></div>

 <form ng-show="showSingle_Fieldsettings">
  <div class="form-group">
   <label>Field Label(?)</label>
   <br/>
   <input ng-model="selectedField.single" class="fieldLabel">
  </div>
 </form>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I think you might be confused, above code is totally not angular way. [This q&a will be great insight](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background) for you.